# Load images on an applet HTML

Tags: java, html, eclipse, image, applet

I'm trying to make a simple game that only renders 4 images on screen randomly, but I want to put try it on a website on an HTML. When I test on Eclipse it works just fine, but when I put it on an html and upload it to the websites it tells me: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "Sheet.png" "read"), I know I have to put getResourceAsStream("Sheet.png");

but it just doesn't work Please help!

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

public BufferedImage icons = null;
public BufferedImage wall = null;
public Random r = new Random();
public boolean running;
private InputStream input;

public Game(){

    setBackground(Color.white);
    setSize(640, 320);

    input = Game.class.getResourceAsStream("Sheet.png");

    start();
    this.setSize(new Dimension(640, 320));

    try {
        icons = ImageIO.read(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    wall = icons.getSubimage(0, 0, 16, 16);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Apple().init();
}

public void start(){
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
}
public void stop(){
    running = false;
}

public void run() {
    while(running){
        try {
            new Thread().sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
    int rendered;
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(wall, r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(280),null);
    g.drawImage(wall, r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(280),null);
    g.drawImage(wall, r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(280),null);
    g.drawImage(wall, r.nextInt(600), r.nextInt(280),null);
    rendered++;
    g.drawString("Rendered: "+rendered, 0, 290);
}
}
```

Applet class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Apple extends JApplet{

public void init(){
    this.start();
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setEnabled(true);
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 320));
    this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(640, 320));
    this.setSize(new Dimension(640, 320));
    this.add(new Game());
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<html><body>
<p>
<applet code="Apple.class" archive="Applet.jar"
width="640" height="320"></applet>
</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: 1) *"when I put it on an html and upload it to the websites"*  What is the URL where we can visit the applet? 2) `width="640" height="320"` that in the HTML is good, but remove all the other references to setting sizes - they are unnecessary & less than helpful. 3) Don't call `start()` from within the `init()` method.  Those methods should only be called by the JVM. 4) Don't mix Swing and AWT components without good reason, in this case, replace the `Canvas` with a `JPanel`. 5) Replace `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` with `e.printStackTrace()` 6) `g.drawImage(wall,..nextInt(280),this);`

Comment: I changed all you told me but it still tells me the same error, but in Eclipse it works fine. the URL is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53271378/Applet/untitled%20text.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some 'bad news' for you.  The applet works just fine here.

[image: Working applet]

This suggests that the problems you see are the result of caching of older classes.  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is open and flush the cache before reloading the page.

Comment: Wow great thanks a lot I hope I have more "bad news" if I encounter more problems, thanks a lot :)